# Rails 4 - HTML in JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

How can I serve JSON response IN Rails 4  that consists of HTML in format

```
{"result" : "<div><p>Some content #1</p><div><p>Some content #2</p><div><p>Some content #3</p>"}
```

Can this be done using active model serializers ?

I want to pre-format my response with data from DB, and then append it to body.

Comment: Do  you already tried this?

Comment: No, I have tried to reutrn JSON response containing some data. But I don't know how to format that response.

Comment: You should move your html to a partial and then use `{ html: render_to_string(partial: 'path/partial', :layout => false) }` for your json response.

Answer (score 1):

[ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html)

```
# Serialize preferences using JSON as coder.
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :preferences, JSON
end
```